# jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication getPassword() null

Tags: java, authentication, liferay, jcifs

I trying to do integrating with AD with jcifs. Each time I do getPassword(), I get null. As I am using WMA. Each time Firefox will prompt for username/password . How to get the password entered by user? I able to get the username with .getName();

Answer (score 0):

For the second question:
[Firefox and not prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809317/configure-firefox-3-0-x-to-authenticate-with-kerberos-and-not-prompt)

This if you already configured silent authentication using kerberos.

Comment: hi volothamp, thanks for the response. but u didnt get it. i do not might firefox prompt for username/password.  what i want to do is ,capture the password in my code

Comment: I see. Sorry, I can't help you, but from what I've know, it won't be that easy. Password are never stored in clear, except for basic authentication.

Bye!